# Need help identifying Windows UI control

Tags: winapi, tabs, uicontrol

Can anyone identify the control that is being used to create the accordion-style tab layout in this Windows dialog?

http://code-industry.net/images/imageprinter_pro.png

Comment: It's certainly not a standard Windows control. But is it Delphi, wxwidgets, Qt, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a standard Windows control. Probably it is a control created by the author of this specific application.